# AppleScript NSWorkspaceDidLaunchApplicationNotification don't get event

Tags: applescript, nsnotificationcenter

I am new to applescript, This simple AppleScript must wait until any application lunch and then display notification for test, but nothing happened!

any solution ?
thanks

```
script Autopilot
property NSWorkspace : class "NSWorkspace"

on run
    tell (NSWorkspace's sharedWorkspace())'s notificationCenter() to ¬
        addObserver:me selector:"notificationDelegate:" |name|:"NSWorkspaceDidLaunchApplicationNotification" object:(missing value)
end run

on notificationDelegate:sender
    display notification "notify"
end notificationDelegate:
end script
```

Comment: The code works in an AppleScriptObjC application in Xcode however in the`applicationDidFinishLaunching` handler

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
property NSWorkspace : class "NSWorkspace" of current application
```